# How to Find the Length of a Column in VBA with a Variable Last Row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a beginner to vba and hope to use it in order to automate a process. I have a computer program that provides me an excel spreadsheet, where the amount of data in the columns can change. For example, I could have a column of length 9 one time:

1

3

2

4

24

23

432

55

2

Or a column of length 5 (note: actual column sizes are usually in the thousands):

1

2

3

4

8

I want to write code that will grab this column, not knowing how long the column will be. Something like:

```
Dim list1 As Array
'I don't know how to find the upper bound
list1 = Range("A1:A" & Upper Bound).Value
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with constant values in these columns and are working with larger amounts of cells in these columns, it could be useful to use the count function:

```
dim x As Long
x = Worksheets(*sheet name*).Range(*column range*).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

x is being passed the number of non-empty cells in your column. So you may want to be careful in your column range not to include any headers, if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will get you the last row.  You might need to be careful if you're looking to count all values (e.g. the first couple rows are blank).

```
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Did you mean xlUp? xlDown sent me to the bottom of the spreadsheet

Comment: Are you trying to do this in VBA? Did you test it in VBA? (Maybe with the debugger?) That code works for me in another application.  I stole it from some google search last year.  There are a lot of google results on this question.  Here's a promising link:
http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from column A into a 2d variant array, use the following:

```
Dim vA As Variant

vA = [a1:index(a:a,counta(a:a))]
```

This assumes that there are no blank cells within the data, and that the data starts in row 1.